# How can I express a two body HFB hamiltonian in a quasi particle HFB base?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, linear-algebra, mean-field-theory

The problem is the flowing:

Let $H$ be the standard two body Hamiltonian:

$$H=\sum_{ab}t_{ab}c_{a}^{+}c_{b}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{ab}v_{abcd}c_{a}^{+}c_{b}^{+}c_{c}c_{d}$$

Were {$c_{a}^{+}c_{a}$} is the standard basis. Given de  HBF transformation {$ \beta_a^{+}=\sum_{b} (U_{ab}c^{+}_{b}+V_{ab}c_{b})$}

Prove that in this new basis{$\beta_{a}^{+}\beta_{a}$} the Hamiltonian takes the form

(used in Ring & Schuck in appendix E)

$$H=H_0+\sum_{ab}H^{11}_{ab}\beta_{a}^{+}\beta_{b}+(\sum_{ab}H^{20}_{ab}\beta_{a}^{+}\beta_{b}^{+}+h.c)+...$$

And compute $H_0$ $H^{11}$ and $H^{20}$.

I assume that I have to take the inverse HFB transformation, 
replace in the Hamiltonian and operate but I'm struggling with the algebra. In my textbooks (Ring & Schuck, Blaizot & Ripka, etc.) this change is always assumed and never proved.

Does anyone know the procedure to prove this or were can I find it?

Comment: Are these bosons or fermions? Preserving the commmutation relations gives very different conditions on the  $U$ and $V$ matrices  in the two cases.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

The particles a fermions they follow anti commutation rules

Comment: @mike stone Thank you for answering. The particles a fermions they follow anti commutation rules